# Executing a flat binary file under Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

Is there a way to execute a flat binary image in Linux, using a syntax something like:

```
nasm -f bin -o foo.bin foo.asm
runbinary foo.bin
```

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use a format like elf (put through a linker)?

Comment: I'm trying to make my code as small as possible.

Comment: Which is only an academic wish. It did not make any real sense for a system which is running a full featured OS to have a single executable which "saves" some bytes of an elf header. Nice to play with but without any real use case.OK, maybe if you want to send a minimal virus included in a sms :-)

Comment: From a link-only answer: https://www.tablix.org/~avian/blog/archives/2016/08/linux_loader_for_dos_like_com_files/ shows a slightly overcomplicated method that `mmap`s the flat binary at virtual address `0`, and sets `rsp` to 64k before jumping into it (still in 64-bit mode, so use it with `.asm` files that have `bits 64`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there some reason you don't want to use "-f elf" instead of "-f bin"?

I think Linux won't run a binary that's not in ELF format.  I can't find a tool that converts flat binaries to ELF, but you can cheat by putting the ELF information in foo.asm,
using the technique described [here](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) :

> We can look at the ELF
>   specification, and
>   /usr/include/linux/elf.h, and
>   executables created by the standard
>   tools, to figure out what our empty
>   ELF executable should look like. But,
>   if you're the impatient type, you can
>   just use the one I've supplied here:
>
> ```
>  BITS 32
>
>                org     0x08048000
>
>  ehdr:                                                 ; Elf32_Ehdr
>                db      0x7F, "ELF", 1, 1, 1, 0         ;   e_ident
>        times 8 db      0
>                dw      2                               ;   e_type
>                dw      3                               ;   e_machine
>                dd      1                               ;   e_version
>                dd      _start                          ;   e_entry
>                dd      phdr - $$                       ;   e_phoff
>                dd      0                               ;   e_shoff
>                dd      0                               ;   e_flags
>                dw      ehdrsize                        ;   e_ehsize
>                dw      phdrsize                        ;   e_phentsize
>                dw      1                               ;   e_phnum
>                dw      0                               ;   e_shentsize
>                dw      0                               ;   e_shnum
>                dw      0                               ;   e_shstrndx
>
>  ehdrsize      equ     $ - ehdr
>
>  phdr:                                                 ; Elf32_Phdr
>                dd      1                               ;   p_type
>                dd      0                               ;   p_offset
>                dd      $$                              ;   p_vaddr
>                dd      $$                              ;   p_paddr
>                dd      filesize                        ;   p_filesz
>                dd      filesize                        ;   p_memsz
>                dd      5                               ;   p_flags
>                dd      0x1000                          ;   p_align
>
>  phdrsize      equ     $ - phdr
>
>  _start:
>
>  ; your program here
>
>   filesize      equ     $ - $$
> ```
>
> This image contains an ELF header,
>   identifying the file as an Intel 386
>   executable, with no section header
>   table and a program header table
>   containing one entry. Said entry
>   instructs the program loader to load
>   the entire file into memory (it's
>   normal behavior for a program to
>   include its ELF header and program
>   header table in its memory image)
>   starting at memory address 0x08048000
>   (which is the default address for
>   executables to load), and to begin
>   executing the code at _start, which
>   appears immediately after the program
>   header table. No .data segment, no
>   .bss segment, no commentary — nothing
>   but the bare necessities.
>
> So, let's add in our little program:
>
> ```
>  ; tiny.asm
>                org     0x08048000
>
>  ;
>  ; (as above)
>  ;
>
> _start: mov bl, 42 xor eax, eax inc eax int 0x80 filesize equ $ - $$
> ```
>
> and try it out:
>
> ```
>  $ nasm -f bin -o a.out tiny.asm
>  $ chmod +x a.out
>  $ ./a.out ; echo $?
>  42
> ```

Comment: Could I make a C program that would load a flat binary into its own code space and execute it?

Comment: I suppose it's possible, but really, you should just use ELF and not worry about a few bytes of overhead.

Comment: You can, as long as your environment lets you run data as code.

Comment: @Stefano: I've only been here a week. Stay tuned. :-)

Comment: ELF is sweet for doing this, you haven't seen the PE headers.

Answer (score 10):

The Linux kernel can load several different binary formats - ELF is just the most common, though the a.out format is also pretty well known.

The supported binary formats are controlled by which binfmt modules are loaded or compiled in to the kernel (they're under the Filesystem section of the kernel config).  There's a `binfmt_flat` for uClinux BFLT flat format binaries which are pretty minimal - they can even be zlib compressed which will let you make your binary even smaller, so this could be a good choice.

It doesn't look like nasm natively supports this format, but it's pretty easy to add the necessary header manually as Jim Lewis describes for ELF.  There's a description of the format [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090101125605/https://www.beyondlogic.org/uClinux/bflt.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Minimally, Linux will need to figure out the format of the executable and it will get that from the first bytes. For example, if it's a script that will be #!, *shebang*. If it's ELF that will be 0x7F 'E' 'L' 'F'. Those magic numbers will determine the handler from a lookup.

So you're gonna need a header with a recognized magic number. You can get a list of shebang supported formats in */proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc*. Getting a list of native binary formats is (unfortunately) [a little trickier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311306/list-of-executable-formats-on-linux).

[bFLT](https://web.archive.org/web/20090101125605/https://www.beyondlogic.org/uClinux/bflt.htm) may be a good choice. Indeed, it's a popular embedded executable format. But you can also squeeze ELF down quite far. [This article](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html) got an ELF executable down to 45 bytes. That said, you'd be squeezing it down mostly by hand rather than by tool.