# List of executable formats on Linux

Tags: linux, format, executable, elf

Where do I find the list of approved/supported executable formats on my Linux system? I am expecting to find a list that contains **ELF**, **Shebang**, **a.out** etc.
I already know that I can find in `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc` a list of user added supported formats, but I want to see the built-in formats in the system. Where can I get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel configuration file has a section named **Executable file formats / Emulations**. The file is named **/boot/config-`uname -r`** on some Linux distributions like Fedora for example.

Some of the available options for [3.14.12](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/log/?id=refs/tags/v3.14.12) x86 (64 bit) are:

- [CONFIG_BINFMT_ELF](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/Kconfig.binfmt?id=refs/tags/v3.14.12#n1)
- [CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/fs/Kconfig.binfmt?id=refs/tags/v3.14.12#n68)

  > Say Y here if you want to execute interpreted scripts starting with
  >   #! followed by the path to an interpreter.
- [CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/Kconfig?id=refs/tags/v3.14.12#n2356)

  > Include code to run legacy 32-bit programs under a 64-bit kernel.

  - [CONFIG_IA32_AOUT](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/Kconfig?id=refs/tags/v3.14.12#n2367):

    > Support old a.out binaries in the 32bit emulation.
  - [CONFIG_X86_X32](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/Kconfig?id=refs/tags/v3.14.12#n2373):

    > Include code to run binaries for the x32 native 32-bit ABI for
    >   64-bit processors. An x32 process gets access to the full 64-bit
    >   register file and wide data path while leaving pointers at 32
    >   bits for smaller memory footprint.

kernel-3.14.1-200.fc20.x86_64 comes with this configuration:

```
CONFIG_BINFMT_ELF=y
CONFIG_COMPAT_BINFMT_ELF=y
CONFIG_ARCH_BINFMT_ELF_RANDOMIZE_PIE=y
CONFIG_CORE_DUMP_DEFAULT_ELF_HEADERS=y
CONFIG_BINFMT_SCRIPT=y
# CONFIG_HAVE_AOUT is not set
CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC=m
CONFIG_COREDUMP=y
CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION=y
# CONFIG_IA32_AOUT is not set
# CONFIG_X86_X32 is not set
```